# How do I make a buffer automatically scroll to its end?

Tags: scrolling

I have a buffer in which the pressed keys echo, and I want the cursor in it always be at the very end. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663061/emacs-auto-scrolling-log-buffer

> Then do a `(set (make-local-variable 'window-point-insertion-type) t)`
>   inside this log buffer. If the cursor is then placed at the end of the
>   buffer, it should stay there (at the end) when text is appended, thus
>   causing scrolling as needed.

PS: This solution needs evil insert mode and the cursor at the end, so it isn't very satisfactory. An elisp minor mode would be much better, if someone knows how to write it.

Comment: Hitting `C-End` is another way to do it, but it's not permanent.  If you switch away and then switch back, it forgets  You have to hit `C-End` again to keep scrolling locked at the bottom.  This solution also works in vanilla Emacs and does NOT require evil.